# How to construct the probability of default (PD) with not much historical data (<1 year)?

Tags: statistics, credit-risk, default-probability, ifrs9

If a financing company has a new funding program, is there a statistical method that can be used to construct a probability of default (PD) for IFRS 9 ECL calculation purposes? Considering that historical data is very minimal, less than one year.
Thanks for your input!

Comment: Hi, is the company publicly traded? I wanted to ask if there could be CDS spreads out there that can be converted into short-term PD estimates. Because since your data is not much, I don't think a long-term estimate would be possible for PD.